# How to display decimals from vs code to ms access

Tags: vb.net

Ok So,
im making a grading system for students as my first project with databases in vb.net

now when i get the average in decimal value and i save it to show in ms access it says it saved but when i check ms access it never saves it unless i enter values that make the average a whole number
now i went in ms access to change property of the average textbox to allow decimal places but the problem is in vs code and all my dims are already in Double
i.e

```
Dim average As Double
```

now i dont think i need to show code but i still will

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Me.Student_GradesBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(StudentGradesDataSet)
            MsgBox("Success")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Please try again")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

```
  Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Try
            Dim geo As Double
            Dim comp As Double
        Dim maths As Double
        Dim sci As Double
        Dim grade As String
        Dim avg As Double

        geo = GeographyTextBox.Text
        sci = ScienceTextBox.Text
        maths = MathematicsTextBox.Text
        comp = ComputerTextBox.Text

            If ((geo > 100) Or (sci > 100) Or (comp > 100) Or (maths > 100)) Then
                MsgBox("Marks cannot be more than 100")
                End
            End If


            avg = (geo + sci + comp + maths) / 4

        If avg < 60 Then
            grade = "Failed"
        Else
            grade = "Passed"
        End If

        AverageTextBox.Text = avg
            GradeTextBox.Text = grade
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("try")
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: It's probably related with the Region, just try to write directly in AverageTextBox the value 1.5 and save it, then the value 1,5 and save it. Check which one worked and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Start by ensuring that you've enabled [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Comment: I’m not seeing anywhere that looks like your writing the average back to the db.  Have you setup data bindings to the AverageTextBox control?